# Can Thunderbird auto-click "email confirmation" emails?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'm very new to using Thunderbird on XUbuntu. I'm learning about filters, plugins, etc.

It would save a lot of time for me in the long run if Thunderbird could open email confirmation links.

For instance, when I register an account on Stack Exchange, I have to confirm my email before I can log in. I've tried some filters to auto move these types of emails into a "new account" folder. It looks like Thunderbird can run scripts, and I'm hoping this is possible.

However, in the past fifteen minutes I haven't found any clues as to if this is possible (or how it would be done).

Comment: Do you just want to move these to a dedicated folder, or have Thunderbird click the verification link for you?  If the latter, there is no native way to do that.

Comment: I was wanting the link to be clicked.